# Purcell enhancement and transitional dipole moment of a quantum dot?

Tags: plasmon, optics

Let us consider a quantum emitter with a transitional dipole moment $\mathbf{p}$  and transitional frequency $\omega_0$ which is placed in an inhomogeneous environment. Its spontaneous decay rate is enhanced by the Purcell effect and can be described mathematically as [Principle of Nano-Optics, L. Novotny and B. Hecht, page 247]:
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{\pi \omega_0}{3\hbar\epsilon_0}|\mathbf{p}|^2\rho_{\text{p}}(\mathbf{r}_0,\omega_0)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho_{\text{p}}(\mathbf{r}_0,\omega_0)=\frac{6\omega_0}{\pi c^2 |\mathbf{p}|^2}\left[ \mathbf{p} \cdot \text{Im}  \left[\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{r}_0,\mathbf{r}_0;\omega_0) \right] \cdot\mathbf{p} \right]
\end{equation}
How does this apply to a semi-conductor quantum dot (QD)? If I understand correctly, a (spherical) QD does not have a well-defined transitional dipole moment vector $\mathbf{p}$ and can be excited by an electric field in any direction, so the above equations are no longer valid. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Please define your notation. For example, what the heck is $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{G}}$?

Comment: Thank you. It is the dyadic green's function of the electromagnetic field of the system. Please see [link](https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Courses/PhysicalOpticsII/notes4.pdf)